# Application Gateways get 404 code from backend pools

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway

I have an App Service as Backend Pools for the Azure Application Gateway.

The app (nextjs app) is working fine but from Application Gateway, it's receiving 404 code from health check.

What am I missing here? Thank you!

Comment: Page not found. Check whether the host name path is accessible on the backend server. Change the host name or path parameter to an accessible value.
Please refer [HTTP status code mismatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-backend-health-troubleshooting#http-status-code-mismatch)

Comment: Yes, probably you have some misspelling somewhere or another get/post issues.